# Scroll to top in nested Drawer navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-v6

I have a nested Drawer navigation and want to scroll to top on every screen change, I am using UseScrollToTop hook as described in the docs but it's not working, are there any other ways guys?

```js
const Home = ({ navigation }) => {
 const ref = useRef(null);

 useScrollToTop(ref);

 return (
 <View>
 <View style={styles.booksContainer}>
 <FlatList
 ref={ref}
 numColumns={2}
 data={DATA}
 renderItem={({ item }) => (
 <HomeItem item={item} navigation={navigation} />
 )}
 keyExtractor={item => item.id}
 />
 </View>
 </View>
 );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone that will have the same problem, I think useScrollToTop hook only works with the Tab navigation.

This is what worked for me.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
      ref.current.scrollToIndex({ animated: true, index: 0 });
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);
```